# Verben mit Präpositionen und angeschlossene Infinitive

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, infinitive

Ich habe eine Frage zur Verwendung der Infinitive nach Verben mit Präpositionen.
Als Beispiel liefere ich die folgende zwei Sätze:

> *Ich sehne mich danach, euch wiederzusehen.*
>
> *Ich sehne mich nach euch, wiederzusehen.*

Welcher ist richtig?

Hängt diese Grammatikregel vom Kasus ab, den das Verb verlangt?

Comment: *Sich nach etwas sehnen* ist auf jeden Fall reflexiv, es müsste also *ich sehne **mich** danach* oder *ich sehne **mich** nach euch* heißen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wie sich eine Infinitivgruppe an ein Verb anschließt, hängt alleine vom Verb ab. Das Verb *sich nach etwas sehnen* verlangt einen Anschluss mit *nach*, deswegen muss es richtig heißen:

> Ich sehne mich danach, euch wiederzusehen.

Dein zweiter Vorschlag ist in seiner jetzigen Form nicht korrekt. *Nach euch* wirkt alleine bereits als Anschluss an *sehnen,* das heißt, ein richtiger Satz wäre:

> Ich sehne mich nach euch.

Hier sehnt man sich aber nicht nach dem Wiedersehen, sondern nur nach den Personen, ohne die Art des Sehnens näher zu definieren. Deswegen kann in diesem Satz *wiederzusehen* nicht erscheinen, und *euch* ist nicht länger ein Objekt von *jemanden wiedersehen,* sondern eines von *sich nach jemandem sehnen.* Klarer wird das vielleicht, wenn man die Person wechselt, um Dativ und Akkusativ besser unterscheiden zu können:

> Ich sehne mich danach, **dich** wiederzusehen.
>
> Ich sehne mich nach **dir.**

Das heißt auch, dass wenn du dich sowohl nach der Person als auch nach dem Wiedersehen sehnst, du den Satz entsprechend ausbauen müsstest:

> Ich sehne mich nach euch; danach, euch wiederzusehen.
>
> Ich sehne mich nach dir; danach, dich wiederzusehen.

Auch wenn *euch* (Dativ) und *euch* (Akkusativ) formengleich sind, kann man sie nicht zusammenfassen.

(Der Strichpunkt kann auch ein Komma sein, aber die Trennung dort ist stärker, weil es prinzipiell zwei Sätze sind, die nur zusammengezogen wurden.)

Answer (score 1):

Das Wort *sehnen* ist im deutschen ein reflexives Verb. Daher können *[üblicherweise]* nur folgende Konstellationen vorkommen:

- ich sehne mich
- du sehnst dich
- er/sie/es sehnt sich
- wir sehnen uns
- ihr sehnt euch
- sie sehnen sich

im genannten Beipspiel verlangt das Verb *wiedersehen* den 4. Fall, im Beispiel ist das *euch*

Der richtige Satz lautet also

> Ich sehne **mich** danach, euch wiederzusehen.

Weitere Beispiele siehe diese [Wiktionary Quelle](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sehnen)

Comment: Ist das Komma notwendig? (Alte/Neue Rechtschreibeordnung?)

Comment: Das Komma ist in diesem Fall notwendig, ja. [siehe 3. Beispiel hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sehnen)

Comment: @RalphM.Rickenbach Gemäß § 75 (3) der amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln wird die Infinitivgruppe mit Komma abgetrennt, da sie von einem Korrelat oder Verweiswort („danach“) abhängt. Wenn ein bloßer Infinitiv vorliegt, kann das Komma weggelassen werden, sofern kein Missverständnis entsteht (z. B. „Ich sehne mich danach(,) zu gehen.“).

Comment: @Medi1Saif allerdings geht es in dem Beispiel des OPs ja um den Nebensatz mit Verb, der in deinem Satz fehlt.

Comment: Dass OP *sich sehnen* fälschlicherweise nicht reflexiv verwendet hat, ist zwar richtig und einer Korrektur wert; die Frage dreht sich allerdings mehr um den Anschluss des gesehnten an das Verb, deswegen hätte ich lieber das fehlende Reflexivpronomen in die Frage hineineditiert und einen klärenden Kommentar hinterlassen, um die Antwort auf den Kernpunkt zu konzentrieren.