# Wie kann ein Nebensatz an Präpositionalverben angehängt werden?

Tags: preposition, pronoun, subordinate-clause

Es gibt Verben mit Präpositionen, wie:

- *abhängen von* + Dativ
- *achten auf* + Akkusativ
- *ärgern über* + Akkusativ

Es gibt auch Nebensätze

- *wie viele Aufgaben ich habe*
- *was du mir gesagt hast*
- *was von oben kommt*

Ich habe Schwierigkeiten, wenn ich mit diesen oben genannten zwei Teilen einen Satz aufbauen soll.

Z. B.:

> **A:** Wie viel Stunden musst du pro Woche arbeiten?
>   **B:** Ich arbeite nicht regelmäßig und ***meine Arbeitsstunden hängen davon ab, wie viele Aufgaben ich habe***.
>
> **A:** Warum bist du böse auf mich?
>   **B:** ***Ich ärgere mich darüber, was du mir gesagt hast.***
>
> **A:** Wenn man an einer Baustelle vorbeigeht, ***soll man darauf achten, was von Oben kommt***.

Ich würde gerne mehr über die dahinterliegenden Regeln erfahren.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/28079/15318

Comment: Einzig beim zweiten Beispiel würde ich "Ich ärgere mich über das, was..." sagen. Oder "Ich ärgere mich darüber, dass...". Sonst klingt das doch alles ganz gut.

Comment: @Em1 "Ich ärgere mich über das, was ... ". Kann man auch so sagen? **Ich soll mich über das ärgern, was du mir gesagt hast?** oder es geht nur wenn **über** am Ende ist?

Comment: @AdInfinitum Das "über" steht sowieso nicht am Ende. Man kann jetzt darüber diskutieren, ob der Nebensatz direkt an das "das" angeschlossen wird oder erst nach dem Verb. Dazu gibt's hier auch ne Frage, aber habe keinen Link dazu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Regel zum Anschließen von Nebensätzen ist prinzipiell die gleiche wie zum [Anschließen von Infinitiven](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/28079).

Es gibt Verben, die ein direktes Anschließen erlauben. In diesem Fall dürfte alles klar sein, der Nebensatz wird direkt angeschlossen. In diesen Fällen verhält sich der Nebensatz oft wie ein Objekt und kann durch ein entsprechendes Objektpronomen ersetzt werden.

> Ich weiß, dass ich etwas gesagt habe. → Ich weiß *es.*

In vielen Fällen werden Anfügungen aber über Präpositionen angeschlossen. Die Präposition braucht ein Wort, das ihr direkt folgt oder das direkt zu ihr gehört und das sie entsprechend (zum Beispiel im Kasus) beeinflussen kann. Alleine kann ein Nebensatz das nicht erfüllen, weswegen ein entsprechendes Demonstrativpronomen benötigt wird.

> Ich ärgere mich **darüber,** dass du etwas gesagt hast. → Ich ärgere mich *darüber.*

Diese Form ist die einzig Mögliche, wenn es sich um einen Nebensatz handelt, der kein Relativsatz ist.  Sollte ein solcher vorliegen, bietet sich noch eine dritte, oft etwas bessere Variante mit Präposition und Demonstrativpronomen, wobei an letzteres direkt der Relativsatz angehängt wird.

> Ich ärgere mich *über **das,*** was du gesagt hast. → Ich ärgere mich *darüber.*

Es fällt auf, dass auch in diesem Fall *darüber* das Demonstrativpronomen der Wahl ist, wenn kein Relativsatz folgt.

Das alles lässt sich zusammenfassen:

- Zwischen Präposition und Nebensatz muss ein Demonstrativpronomen kommen.
- Wenn der Nebensatz ein Relativsatz ist, *(das, der, was,* …) kann ein artikelgleiches Demonstrativpronomen gewählt werden *(über das, über den,* …)
- Sonst muss (bei Relativsätzen: darf) ein Pronomen der *da*-Reihe *(darüber, davon, darauf,* …) gewählt werden.

---

Diese Regel gilt auch, wenn das Demonstrativpronomen nicht das letzte Satzglied ist:

> Ich soll mich über das ärgern, was du gesagt hast?
>
> Ich soll mich darüber ärgern, was du gesagt hast?

Natürlich darf aber auch umgestellt werden:

> Ich soll mich über das, was du gesagt hast, ärgern?

Grundsätzlich würde ich bei Relativsätzen wahrscheinlich eher die *das*-Variante wählen.

Comment: Warum die Fragezeichen in den Beispielen, z.B „Ich soll mich über das ärgern, was du gesagt hast?“ Ist „Soll ich mich über das ärgern, was du gesagt hast?“ falsch?

Comment: @starkhalo Gute Frage. Beide sind richtig werden aber typischerweise unterschiedlich verwendet. Bei »Soll ich …?« gehe ich von einer ernst gemeinten Frage aus; ich weiß also nicht, ob ich mich ärgern soll. Bei »Ich soll …?« steht für mich fest, dass ich keinen Grund sehe, mich zu ärgern, aber anscheinend möchte die andere Person das.